# React.js : values.hobbies is not iterable

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error when I try and map over the hobbies array. How can I display the hobbies checked list.I don't know what is wrong with the handleCheckboxChange function and also while I'm displaying it is throwing an error.Also,I'm not getting how can I display the checkbox value on UsersList page.
Here's the code :

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
  Button,
  Col,
  FormFeedback
} from 'reactstrap'
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
import axios from 'axios'

const AddUser = () => {
  const { addUser } = useContext(GlobalContext)
  const history = useHistory()
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    fullname: '',
    fullnameError: '',
    birthdate: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/'),
    address: '',
    gender: '',
    college: [],
    hobbies: []
  })
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const err = validate()
    if (!err) {
      newUser()
    }
  }

  const newUser = () => {
    const newwUser = {
      id: uuid(),
      fullname: values.fullname,
      birthdate: values.birthdate,
      address: values.address,
      college: values.college,
      gender: values.gender,
      hobbies: values.hobbies
    }
    addUser(newwUser)
    history.push('/userslist')
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(name) {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://universities.hipolabs.com/search`, {
        params: { name }
      }
      )
      console.log(response.data)
      setValues({ college: response.data })
    }
    fetchData('Middle')
  }, [])

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValues({
      ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  const handleCheckboxChange = event => {
    let newArray = [...values.hobbies, event.target.id];
    if (values.hobbies.includes(event.target.id)) {
      newArray = newArray.filter(hobby => hobby !== event.target.id);
    }
    setValues({
      hobbies: newArray
    })
  }
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>Select Your Hobbies</Label>
        <FormGroup>
          <Input type="checkbox" name="travelling" value='travelling' id="exampleCheck" onChange=
            {handleCheckboxChange} />
          <Label for="exampleCheck">Travelling</Label>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
          <Input type="checkbox" name="reading" value='reading' id="exampleCheck" onChange=
            {handleCheckboxChange} />
          <Label for="exampleCheck">Reading</Label>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
          <Input type="checkbox" name="gaming" value='gaming' id="exampleCheck" onChange=
            {handleCheckboxChange} />
          <Label for="exampleCheck">Gaming</Label>
        </FormGroup>
      </FormGroup>
      {values.hobbies && values.hobbies.map((hobby, index) => {
        return <p key={index}>{hobby}</p>
      })}
      <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  )
}

export default AddUser
```

Comment: Please, format the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

> This is because when we update a state variable, we replace its value. This is different from this.setState in a class, which merges the updated fields into the object.

can refer to [Should I use one or many state variables?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables)

---

```
 const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
    let newArray = [...values.hobbies, event.target.id];
    if (values.hobbies.includes(event.target.id)) {
      newArray = newArray.filter((hobby) => hobby !== event.target.id);
    }
    
// This set value will replace the values become only contain hobbies
    setValues({
      hobbies: newArray,
    });

  };
```

need to include previous value by

```
setValues({
  ...values,
  hobbies: newArray
})
```

another one is

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(name) {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://universities.hipolabs.com/search`,
        {
          params: { name },
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);

// here
      setValues({ college: response.data });
    }
    fetchData("Middle");
  }, []);
```

this `setValues` inside `useEffect` should become

```
setValues({ ...values, college: response.data })
```